# ExpandableListView affecting the size of Scrollview when collapsing and expanding

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

Let me try to explain what I want to achieve. Currently, I have a ScrollView as the main view for my layout and a linearLayout within that to place all of my content into.

In my LinearLayout, I have a bunch of textviews and a gallery, which extends out of the screen, so the user can scroll to see everything. It works.

Now, I want to add an expandableListView to the bottom of all that content, which is still in the linearLayout. The problem is when you expand the list view groups it doesn't affect the ScrollView. I had envisaged that when you expand a group it would make the linearLayout bigger, which in turn makes the scrollview bigger.

Is what I'm thinking achievable?

EDIT:

Ok I think the situation is that listViews are normally placed in a layout by themselves and have scrollviews already enabled. You just set it to fill_parent and it works fine. However, in my case, I'll need the expandableListView to display all content without scrolling, because my ScrollView will deal with that. I don't even think it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answert without seeing your layout xml, but I think that if you set the  android:layout_height of the linear layout and expandableListView to wrap_content, the first  scrollView must scroll the whole view.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried putting your expandable list into another linear layout and than put it in the scroll views default linear layout?